# Powershell GUI script combobox usage

Tags: user-interface, powershell, process, combobox

I'm programming a Powershell GUI script that shows a list of all the processes names running on the system using a combobox.

I would like to show process name followed by the proccess ID in parenthesis. 
i.e.

```
Internet explorer (4)
Chrome (100)
Skype (33)
```

This is the code I've got. So far I can just show the process name, I don't know how to show the process id as well, any advise?

```
$MainForm_Load={
#TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
$processes = Get-Process
foreach ($process in $processes)
{
    Load-ComboBox $combobox1 $process.ProcessName  -Append 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Format String (-f)

```
$MainForm_Load={
#TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
$processes = Get-Process
foreach ($process in $processes)
{
$CurrentProcess = "{0} ({1})" -f $process.Name,$process.id   
Load-ComboBox $combobox1 $CurrentProcess -Append 
}
```

Regarding your Comment Question,

first it should be: `get-process $combobox1.selecteditem.text` but it still not going to work because for example the name "Chrome (100)" is not a valid process name, so you need to split it first to remove the process id (100),

you can try this

```
$ProcessName = ($combobox1.selecteditem.text) -replace "\(.*\)"
```

then use

```
$textbox1.text = (get-process $ProcessName) | Out-String
```

Comment: Brilliant!, Is there any particular website where I can check this kind of syntax? I know this is very basic stuff, but I am staring on Powershell GUI scripts...

Now the issue I've got is that I want to show information about the specific process selected and this doesn't work anymore...

    $buttonView_Click={
     #TODO: Place custom script here
     if ($combobox1.SelectedIndex -gt -1)
     {
      $textbox1.Text=Get-Process ($combobox1.SelectedItem) |     Out-String
     }
 
    }

Comment: If I use "$combobox1.selecteditem.text" it says that Name is null.
Where as if I try this, it works perfectly: $ProcessName = ($combobox1.SelectedItem) -replace " \(.*\)"
  $textbox1.Text=(Get-Process $ProcessName) | Out-String

Note that I also had to add a blank space to -replace " \(.*\)" Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
get-process | %{$combobox.items.add("$($_.name)($($_.id))")}
```